# MKMarkerAnnotationView has a truncated image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, mapkit, mkannotationview

I want to get a UIImage from a MKMarkerAnnotationView but with the following code the image is truncated (at the top and bottom, see the screenshot)

```
let newAnnotation = SimpleAnnotation(sourceCoordinate: annotation.coordinate, sourceTitle: "Hello", sourceSubtitle: "world")
let pinAnnotation = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: newAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "Test")
pinAnnotation.markerTintColor = UIColor.red
pinAnnotation.glyphText = "1"
pinAnnotation.animatesWhenAdded = false
pinAnnotation.glyphTintColor = UIColor.white
pinAnnotation.titleVisibility = .hidden
pinAnnotation.subtitleVisibility = .hidden

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pinAnnotation.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
pinAnnotation.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x:0,
                                       y:0,
                                       width:pinAnnotation.bounds.width,
                                       height:pinAnnotation.bounds.height),
                            afterScreenUpdates: true)
let snapshotImageFromMyView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Any idea why it's truncated? In the Xcode debugger I can see the image is already truncated in the pinAnnotation (before I use UIGraphics... to get the UIImage)

[image]

Comment: You're assuming that the size of the image is limited to the size of the pin annotation's bounds. Maybe that's not true. An image can exceed the bounds of the view that portrays it.

Comment: And then, any idea how to proceed to get the full image?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you should try drawing into a larger context and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution! I have just to set the contentMode to scaleAspectFit and to change the bounds to the size of the image I need (40x40px).

Here's the code displaying the full MKMarkerAnnotationView.

```
let pinAnnotation = MKMarkerAnnotationView()
pinAnnotation.markerTintColor = UIColor.red
pinAnnotation.glyphText = "1"
pinAnnotation.animatesWhenAdded = false
pinAnnotation.glyphTintColor = UIColor.white
pinAnnotation.titleVisibility = .hidden
pinAnnotation.subtitleVisibility = .hidden
pinAnnotation.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
pinAnnotation.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pinAnnotation.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
pinAnnotation.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x:0,
                                       y:0,
                                       width:pinAnnotation.bounds.width,
                                       height:pinAnnotation.bounds.height),
                            afterScreenUpdates: true)
let snapshotImageFromMyView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

This page [Demystifying iOS Layout](http://tech.gc.com/demystifying-ios-layout/) has helped me a lot to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the drawHierarchy to work I just get back an empty image.